# Can I put 255/40 R20 tyres against manufacturer recommended 225/60 R17 on GMC terrain 2015 SLE2 version

Tags: wheels, gmc, terrain

I have GMC terrain SLE2 trim 2015 model with R17 225/60 tyres as manufacturer recommendation. When I bought this car, it was installed with 275/40 R20 tyre. However, now its time for for tyre change, Whats the recommended tyre size with R20 rim ?

Also note Top Level Trim Denali GMC terrain 2015 has 245/45 R20 tyres. So I feel it should be Ok to put same tyre size. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a useful resource when choosing tire sizes:

[Tire Size Calculator](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

Comparing the two sizes you mentioned gives this:

[image: Size Comparison]

Note that the R20 tire, overall, is just a bit larger than the R17 tires.  So clearance-wise it should not be a problem.

You do realize, however, that the number following the "R" is the rim or wheel diameter and you cannot put R20 tires on a 17" rim or R17 tires on a 20" rim.  So to change sizes you will need to replace your rims/wheels.

Comment: The "R" actually denotes ["radial"](https://www.bridgestoneamericas.com/en/company/safety/choosing-tires/determining-tire-size#:~:text=Radial%20tires%20are%20the%20most,to%20the%20direction%20of%20rotation.), meaning it's a radial tire. It was to differentiate them from bias plies which don't have a designation there.

Comment: R20 is 20" rim size, R17 is 17".  But you are correct, "R" means radial.  I'm not sure it's relevant to this question though.

Comment: Just pointing it out as you seem to be confused. I want to ensure nobody else is.